# SciKit-learn - Training a Gaussian Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot the decision surface for a Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier. I seem to be having a bit of a problem with training the classifier though. I am also very new to machine learning.

First I generate 100 random points, with half having a different coordinate and label.

```
for i in range(50):
    point1.append([np.random.randint(50,80),np.random.randint(50,80)])
    point1L.append(1)
for i in range(50):
    point2.append([np.random.randint(10,40),np.random.randint(10,70)])
    point2L.append(0)
```

I then train it.

```
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(point1,point1L)
clf.fit(point2, point2L)
```

I then run into a problem. The classifier I have here doesn't seem to be able to differentiate between the two points.

```
print(clf.predict([np.random.randint(50,80),np.random.randint(50,80)]))
print(clf.predict([np.random.randint(10,40),np.random.randint(10,70)]))
```

The result I get for this always seem to be:

```
[0]
[0]
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

On a side note, I would also like to know if I can plot the decision boundary straight from the classifier itself, and not by comparing decisions by the classifier at every point.

Comment: just switch "fit(x,y)" to "partial_fit(x,y,[0,1])" and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fit()` method should only be called once. You are calling `fit` method two times, one for `point1` and one for `point2`. So when you call `fit()` again for `point2`, the estimator resets itself and only train for `point2L`, which is 0. That's why your predictions are always 0.
First combine the `point1` and `point2` into a new matrix, (same for labels) and then call the `fit` method on new matrix.